# QR-Code in a web service response

Tags: java, web-services, qr-code, zxing

I have to implement a Java SOAP web service that returns the QR Code of a text (an authorization code).
What's the best way to return this QRCode? The base64 encoding of the png, the ByteArrayOutputStream or what?

Tipically, the client will use this web service to embed the QRCode in a web page.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you simply return an image, like the binary PNG/JPEG?  Or, if you want to get fancy, and the QR code can be broken into equal squares, how about a binary matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Do not send it back as a base64 encoded string. It is a waste of space and you cannot stream the image. Simply return the bytes for the files as a stream and give it to the client. Return any meta-data associated with the file (such as `Content-type` `Content-length` ) in the response header.

Answer (score 0):

you can return the data of the image by having your webapp response (assuming it is a servlet) do:

```
byte[] image = getQRCodeAsByteArray();
response.setContentType('image/png')
response.setContentLength(image.length)
response.getOutputStream().write(image)
```

if you then point your web browser at that particular webapp URL, you will see an image

Comment: My web server is a SOAP web server and I would like to use ZXing library for QRCode generation. What returns your getQRCodeAsByteArray() method?

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help me. I have a SOAP Web Service.